# What protocols are involved in sending a message over Ethernet in Java?

Tags: java, networking, tcp, ip, ethernet

I want to send a small packet from one machine to another in same network. Here are the network specifications:

```text
IP of machine A: 192.158.1.10

IP of machine B: 192.158.1.20

Distance between machines: 1 hop

Protocol: TCP

MTU: 1500
```

I want to understand that if I send a small TCP packet (less than MTU) then which protocols are involved in delivering that packet to the destination?

For example if I send a message of size 50 B. Then the end result will be submitting a packet over ethernet + tcp + ip = 24 B + 20 B + 20 =64B will be the header size .... right?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks...

BTW: I am using java to send a packet but it does not matter I guess.

Comment: You can try and use tcpdump to see the whole dialog; but basically here you involve ARP, IP, TCP.

Comment: Thanks. So lets say that we already have the MAC address of target cached at sending computer then we do not need ARP right? We can send a packet directly over ethernet/tcp/tp

Comment: Yes, if you already have the IP<->MAC pair recorded in your local ARP cache, you won't need to invoke ARP again. But then only Ethernet is really used over the wire; the rest is up to the OS to implement.